# Return a value from nested function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, callback, return

I am relatively new to programming.  Would really appreciate some help.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<input id='aContainer' type='radio' name='catContainer' value='a'>
<label for="aContainer">a</label>
<input id='bContainer' type='radio' name='catContainer' value='b'>
<label for="bContainer">b</label>
<input id='cContainer' type='radio' name='catContainer' value='c'>
<label for="cContainer">c</label>
<input id='dContainer' type='radio' name='catContainer' value='d'>
<label for="dContainer">d</label>
```

The javascript code:

```
let containerValue = () => {

   node.childNodes.forEach((container) => {
    container.addEventListener('input', () => {
      let sampleValue;
      if (container.checked == true) {
        sampleValue = container.value;
      }
      console.log(sampleValue); // the result shows up here.
      
    });
  })
}
console.log(containerValue());// Nothing here
```

I am trying to get the value of sampleValue. I am not sure how to return the values with nested functions.

Comment: Does not make sense. The event handlers will be called when a user interacts with the elements. You don't know when that will happen, so returning a value is useless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have added the HTML section. When I click the radio button, the value(sampleValue) from the checked button needs to be passed on to another function.

Comment: `console.log()` is a function that you have called with `sampleValue`. Why not just call your target function in the same way?

Comment: @John So you want to pass the value from the button to the other function every time there is an event? Or just once?

Comment: @Bergi Everytime I click on a radio button, its value needs to be passed (as a result of the function) to the target function. It works until where I have indicated.

Comment: @John Then you need to call that target function from the event handler. It is not possible to have `containerValue()` return the values as a result, since the function can only return a single result, once, when it was called. Not whenever the button is clicked.

Comment: @SimonJacobs it took me time to understand what you were suggesting. But I now realise it is the same solution. Thanks alot.